# Как определить конец файла?

Tags: delphi, php, файлы

Требуется реализовать обмен данными с сайтом. Софт написан на delphi, через сокеты передается строка. на сайте данный скрипт:

```
$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 15);
        if (!$fp) {
            return "errno: $errno \nerrstr: $errstr\n";
        }
        fwrite($fp, rawurlencode($data));
        $response = "";
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $response .= fread($fp, 1);
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

Собственно, цикл (`while (!feof($fp))`) не останавливается, как передать символ конца файла. #26 не подходит.

Answer (score 3):

Вы уверены, что в софте на delphi Вы закрываете сокет? Символа конца файла нет, признак конца файла это закрытый сокет.
Как Вы на delphi корректно читаете, вот это:

```
fwrite($fp, rawurlencode($data));
```

Вам удается прочитать и перейти к записи?